# How to connect my Emulator to Internet.?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am using Ubuntu operating system. I have installed eclipse with recent version of android plug in (kitkat). But my virtual device is not connecting to Internet. I am using wifi Internet so how can I connect it to wifi ?

Comment: If your system has internet connection you no need to do anything special for AVD. Check AVD is in offline mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Data Connection` is disabled in your Emulator. You can enable it by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>. Once you done it, It will show you 3G icon in the title bar of emulator.